# How to use functions more than once in a Custom Class

Tags: ios, function, swift3, xcode8

is there anyway to implement the

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {}
```

twice? I am trying to create a conversion app that has several view controllers in which all have similar `UITextFields`. I followed a great tutorial on www.globalnerdy.com that shows how to create a custom class that will limit characters and only allow certain characters within a given text field. After the code is complete, you can modify the properties within the Attributes Inspector vs. within the View Controller. Below is the `MaxLengthTextField` custom class that I created.

```
class MaxLengthTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

private var characterLimit: Int?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    delegate = self

}

@IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {

    get {

        guard let length = characterLimit else {

            return Int.max

        }

        return length

    }

    set {

        characterLimit = newValue

    }

}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard string.characters.count > 0 else {

        return true

    }

    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""

    let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)


    return allowedIntoTextField(text: prospectiveText)


}

func allowedIntoTextField(text: String) -> Bool {

    return text.characters.count <= maxLength

}

}
```

Here is the AllowedCharacters custom class, the sub-class of MaxLengthTextField.

```
class AllowedCharsTextField: MaxLengthTextField {

@IBInspectable var allowedChars: String = ""

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    delegate = self

    autocorrectionType = .no

}

override func allowedIntoTextField(text: String) -> Bool {

    return super.allowedIntoTextField(text: text) && text.containsOnlyCharactersIn(matchCharacters: allowedChars)

}

}

private extension String {

// Returns true if the string contains only characters found in mainCharacters.
func containsOnlyCharactersIn(matchCharacters: String) -> Bool {

    let disallowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: matchCharacters).inverted

    return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: disallowedCharacterSet) == nil

}
}
```

The problem that I am having is limiting the decimal "." in my code. I have tried implementing the `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn...` function twice by using the code that I found here on Stack Overflow (which works) for limiting decimals but since the specific text field is already a custom class that limits characters, I am unable to make the text field a delegate of the view controller and limit the "dots" at the same time.

Any guidance, references, and straight up help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, methods are uniquely identified by their signature - or the combination of the method name plus the parameters (the type of parameters) that it takes. So, you cannot have the exact same method twice in your code. That will lead to compiler errors.

Rather than implementing the `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {}` method twice, what you should do is look at the passed in `textField` parameter to identify which text field sent the delegate method in the first place.

Make your view controller the `UITextFieldDelegate` and then in your view controller have outlets for your different text fields. So, if your text fields are `text1` and `text2`, your delegate method would look something like this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == text1 {
        // Handle text1 code
    } else if textField == text2 {
        // Handle text2 code
    }
}
```

Hope the above makes sense to you but if not, feel free to ask for clarifications :)